# Table code sintux is not executable in IEEE Template. Please help

Tags: tables, errors

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[!htbp]%[H]
\centering
\caption{{Overall performance evaluation}}
\label{Tab:OPT}
%   \scalebox{0.9}[0.9]{
\begin{tabular}{cccccccccc}
    \toprule
 \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Performance evaluation}}& \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Case study I}& \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Case study II}} \\
    \cmidrule{2-8}
    & \textbf{ANN}
        & \textbf{LSTM}
            & \textbf{CRBM}
                & \textbf{FCRBM}
    & \textbf{ANN}
        & \textbf{LSTM}
            & \textbf{CRBM}
                & \textbf{FCRBM}\\
\midrule
    Computational complexity (level) & {Low} & {High} & {Moderate} & {Moderate} & {Moderate}& {High} & {Moderate} & {Moderate} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: what is your actual question? You have tagged this as longtable, tabularx, siunitx but your example does not use any of those packages?

Comment: you use `\multirow` but do not load the `multirow` package.

Comment: and you have a missing `}` in  `{\textbf{Case study I}}`

Comment: By "sintux", do you mean either "syntax" or "siunitx"? (The latter is a LaTeX package that provides some very neat facilities for tables.) Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the only package that's required to get your table to compile and look reasonably good at the same time is the `booktabs` package.

In the following solution, I've changed `\cmidrule{2-8}` to `\cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(l){6-9}` fix the separation between the upper and lower parts of the header material. I also removed all **bold-facing** from the header cells: If the table is designed well and with a clear layout, there's simply *no need* to resort to cheap tricks -- such as **bold-facing** -- in order to give the table the visual appeal it needs and deserves. Conversely, if a table's layout is substandard, no amount of selective bold-facing will salvate its appearance.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{Overall performance evaluation}
\label{Tab:OPT}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{8}{c} @{}}
    \toprule
 Performance evaluation &  
 \multicolumn{4}{c}{Case study I}& 
 \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{Case study II} \\
 \cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(l){6-9}
    & ANN & LSTM & CRBM & FCRBM 
    & ANN & LSTM & CRBM & FCRBM \\
\midrule
    Computational complexity (level) & 
    Low & High & Moderate & Moderate & 
    Moderate & High & Moderate & Moderate \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow} %added

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[!htbp]%[H]
\centering
\caption{{Overall performance evaluation}}
\label{Tab:OPT}
%   \scalebox{0.9}[0.9]{
\begin{tabular}{cccccccccc}
    \toprule
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Performance evaluation}}& \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Case study I}}& \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Case study II}} \\
    \cmidrule{2-8}
    & \textbf{ANN}
        & \textbf{LSTM}
            & \textbf{CRBM}
                & \textbf{FCRBM}
    & \textbf{ANN}
        & \textbf{LSTM}
            & \textbf{CRBM}
                & \textbf{FCRBM}\\
\midrule
    Computational complexity (level) & {Low} & {High} & {Moderate} & {Moderate} & {Moderate}& {High} & {Moderate} & {Moderate} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I just realized that this answer was already done by  David Carlisle in his comments.